# Iterating through a list containing text to get rid of certain values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, beautifulsoup

I am having a problem cleaning up some data I got by scraping Google News headlines.

I am interested in making a clean dataframe with a few columns from a list I got from my scraping of google news headlines, with the beautifulsoup library.

My list looked like this, and I called it "date":

```
[<div class="slp"><span class="f">ESPN - 13 hours ago</span></div>, <div class="slp"><span class="f">ABS-CBN News - 13 hours ago</span></div>, <div class="slp"><span class="f">New York Times - 14 hours ago</span></div>, <div class="slp"><span class="f">MinnPost - 1 day ago</span></div>, <div class="slp"><span class="f">New York Times - 2 days ago</span></div>, <div class="slp"><span class="f">NME.com - 1 day ago</span></div>, <div class="slp"><span class="f">Wichita Eagle - 1 day ago</span></div>, <div class="slp"><span class="f">Jalopnik - 1 day ago</span></div>]
```

Is there a way I can iterate through this list and get rid of the div tags? I would like to be stuck with just the Newspaper - date for each value in the list.

I tried to use the features of beautifulsoup to do this but didn't have much success and I also tried turning my list into a pandas dataframe and using stuff like 
     df = df.replace('',"")

and writing loops and such but they didn't work.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `BeautifulSoup` to find the element `span`, then get the `text`, like this:

```
import bs4
date_lst = ["""<div class="slp"><span class="f">ESPN - 13 hours ago</span></div>""", 
            """<div class="slp"><span class="f">ABS-CBN News - 13 hours ago</span></div>""",
            """<div class="slp"><span class="f">New York Times - 14 hours ago</span></div>""", 
            """<div class="slp"><span class="f">MinnPost - 1 day ago</span></div>""", 
            """<div class="slp"><span class="f">New York Times - 2 days ago</span></div>""",
            """<div class="slp"><span class="f">NME.com - 1 day ago</span></div>""",
            """<div class="slp"><span class="f">Wichita Eagle - 1 day ago</span></div>""", 
            """<div class="slp"><span class="f">Jalopnik - 1 day ago</span></div>"""]
date_result  = []
for d in date_lst:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(d, "html.parser")
    date_result.append(soup.find('span').text)
print(date_result)
```

**Update:**
Based on your update, the dates contains the `<div class="slp">` element, you can directly loop to find the `span` and get `text`.

```
date_result  = []
for d in dates:
    date_result.append(d.find('span').text)
```

date_result will be:

```
[u'ESPN - 13 hours ago',
 u'ABS-CBN News - 13 hours ago',
 u'New York Times - 14 hours ago',
 u'MinnPost - 1 day ago',
 u'New York Times - 2 days ago',
 u'NME.com - 1 day ago',
 u'Wichita Eagle - 1 day ago',
 u'Jalopnik - 1 day ago']
```

Comment: Is there a way I can make this work but without having date_lst explicitly equal to something,  i would like to use the list "dates" which is generated from my code which looks like this: `code`searchTerm = "something"
count=0
url = ("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + searchTerm + "&hl=en&gl=us&authuser=0&tbs=qdr:y&tbm=nws&start=$count$&cad=h")
dates = []

while (count<30):
    new_url = url.replace("$count$", str(count))
    r = requests.get(new_url)
    
    soup = bs4(r.text, 'html.parser')
    dates += soup.find_all("div", "slp")
    count = count+10

Comment: Thank you so much!! I spent so much time trying different things, to no success! Your solution was so simple and nice...

Comment: @SP welcome to stackoverflow, here you can get the help from other engineers. cheers :) glad to help you. thanks :)

Comment: TY again! Could you please point me to documentation or something as to why this worked so well for finding spans but not for other things? I used the same method for data gathering to collect a list of headlines, ending up with a list of things like this: <div class="st">text i want</div>,...<div class="st">... When i tried to use the same method you gave me, it gave me an error like: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'. I was able to get rid of the div tags through replacing them with spaces. But I think this solution is worse than the one you gave me for finding spans.

Comment: @SP The error message shows that you are trying to call `text` on a None object, suspect your `find` method return `None`. if you want to learn more about `beautifulsoup`, refer to [official doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do something like the below way as well:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content="""
<div class="slp"><span class="f">ESPN - 13 hours ago</span></div> 
<div class="slp"><span class="f">ABS-CBN News - 13 hours ago</span></div>
<div class="slp"><span class="f">New York Times - 14 hours ago</span></div>
<div class="slp"><span class="f">MinnPost - 1 day ago</span></div>
<div class="slp"><span class="f">New York Times - 2 days ago</span></div>
<div class="slp"><span class="f">NME.com - 1 day ago</span></div>
<div class="slp"><span class="f">Wichita Eagle - 1 day ago</span></div>
<div class="slp"><span class="f">Jalopnik - 1 day ago</span></div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
for item in soup.select(".slp .f"):
    print(item.text)
```

Result:

```
ESPN - 13 hours ago
ABS-CBN News - 13 hours ago
New York Times - 14 hours ago
MinnPost - 1 day ago
New York Times - 2 days ago
NME.com - 1 day ago
Wichita Eagle - 1 day ago
Jalopnik - 1 day ago
```